# Categorizing Time in different time intervals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have time in an excel column under format 12:15:00 AM. I have written a formula to categorize this time in different intervals (For E.g. 12:00 AM - 2:00 AM).

The following formula works absolutely fine and it gives me the return value

```
=IF(AND(L3122>=TIMEVALUE("00:00:00"))*(L3122<=TIMEVALUE("02:00:59")),"12:00 AM - 2:00 AM","PROBLEM IN FORMULA")
```

However, when I change the TimeValue from "00:00:00" to "23:00:00" it does not return the right value

```
=IF(AND(L3122>=TIMEVALUE("23:00:01"))*(L3122<=TIMEVALUE("01:00:59")),"11:00 PM - 1:00 AM","PROBLEM IN FORMULA")
```

Can anyone help

Comment: Yes indeed but the actual time in this example is 12:15:00 AM and the second formula should also give me the output "11:00 PM - 1:00 AM". I guess I need to know how to go back to 23:00 Hours in a formula as the formula that starts with 00:00 hours seem to be working

Comment: 12:15am is 00:15. 12:15:00 is 12:15pm

Comment: BTW, you are not quite using the AND function correctly.  its supposed to be AND( arg1, arg2,...,argN)  if all arg# are TRUE then AND returns TRUE.  Right now your AND is only evaluating the portion before the the *.  You should modify your formula to the following `=IF(AND(L3122>=TIMEVALUE("00:00:00"),L3122<=TIMEVALUE("02:00:59")),"12:00 AM - 2:00 AM","PROBLEM IN FORMULA")`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that 12:15:00 AM is less than 23:00:01.  I am not sure what your ultimate goal here is but a little side bar on how date and time are stored in Excel may help you out.

Date and time are stored respectively as integers and decimal.  The integer represents the number of days since 1900/01/01 with that date being counted as 1.  That is why when you type a date into a cell and then set the formatting to general you will get an integer showing and a rather large one for recent dates.  When you set the formatting to display a date format, the integer is still there, but background task in excel changed it to display as something people can easily recognize.

Time in excel is stored as a decimal which represents fract or percent of a day.  So 24:00:00 (which is not an official excel time) is really 1.  And 12 noon is actually 0.5.  Again you can see this when the formatting is changed to general for a cell containing an excel time.  It will come out to some decimal value.

IMPORTANT NOTE.  If the time or date does not change when you set the cell formatting to GENERAL, it means the date or time is really a text/string value.  In order to work with excels built in date and time functions you will need to convert it to an excel date and time value.

When you are looking at time ranges that extend beyond midnight, it can be helpful some times to add in the date to the time. If there is no actually date, but you have a day count you can simply add the day as an integer to the time.  ie record noon on the following day as 1+0.5 = 1.5  or 15 minutes into the morning on the following day as 1+timevalue("00:15:00").  This may not always be the route you want to take and really depends on what you are trying to achieve with your time frame formulas.

#### ALTERNATIVE

You want to check if the time is GREATER THAN 23:00:01 **OR** LESS THAN 01:00:00.  You could modify your formula as follows:

```
=IF(OR(L3122>=TIMEVALUE("23:00:01"),L3122<=TIMEVALUE("01:00:59")),"11:00 PM - 1:00 AM","PROBLEM IN FORMULA")
```